# Is it possible to cache the routes in MVC5?

Tags: c#, caching, routes, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I have more than 150 controllers in an MVC 5 project, with some 5-8 actions for each controller. I have used attribute routing on my controllers. My server response time is very poor; as my controllers do not take any parameters, do not change, I would like to cache the routes.

How I can cache my 800 - 1,000 routes?

Comment: How do you know it is the routing that is slowing responses down?

Comment: When I comment out the  routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); in my route.config, I have 3,5 times faster response time.

Comment: I have route and route prefix attributes on my controllers. An I call my controllers with Html.ActionLink.

Comment: I don't think attribute routing has a cache and uses reflection which is why it is slow. Is it a huge job to revert to 'normal' routing?

Comment: If there is no solution, I will revert to normal routing.. It will take some 16 working hours, I guess. But what I do not understand, I think lots of people use attributeroutes, I found very few questions for "slow websites", with no answers... The other people should have solved this "slow issue", I guess. I want to find out how it is solved.

Comment: Do you use the RoutePrefix attribute at the controller level or just Route attribute at the action level?

Comment: I use both, like  [RoutePrefix("soap/clean")]
    [Route("{action=index}")]

Comment: Answer to defalult routing: No, I dont'. I have only "normal routing" codes in my routeconfig, at the end:   routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Can't you reduce the amount of routes? 800-1000 is a LOT... On your controller (KadikoyController) [RoutePrefix("istanbul/kadikoy")] [Route("{action=index}")] On your action [Route("kadikoy-tarihi")] public ActionResult KadikoyTarihi() why not alter the action name / remove the overiding route?

Comment: P.S. You are using default routing which can be used to reduce the number of routes... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#default-route

Comment: To alter action names, is heavier job than cancelling attributerouting. Normally, is the main problem the amount of routes?

Comment: Have a read of how Stack Overflow overcame a similar issue: http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/13/optimising-asp-net-mvc3-routing

Comment: Large amounts of routes is a cause of performance issues.

Comment: If I group, I can have some 140 default routes in my route.config. Is that then feasible? Is this the solution to increase the performance?

Comment: Without knowing your code base it is difficult to say yes or no, it would be a guess... Here is a possible solution for you, MVCRouteCache http://schwabencode.com/mvcroutecache-vs-attribute-routing/

Comment: I already read these articles, If there is no solution in attributerouting, I will refer to a third party solution like mvcroutecache.

Comment: 140 default routes... if that reduces the number of action level routes dramatically (from say 800 to 400) it seems only logical that this would improve speed.

Comment: Thank you Paul Zahra for your time, your comments. I'll try the default routes.